# VBA index match 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet where I need return a value from one sheet, based on 2 criteria from another sheet. Generally with a formula I would do something like this:

```
index(Sheet1!C1:C100,match(Sheet2!B1&Sheet2!C1, Sheet1!A1:A100&Sheet1!B1:B100,0))
```

but this is an array formula, so Application.WorksheetFunction doesn't seem to work, and I will need to loop this through appox 2,000 rows, so I'm worried it will be too slow.

My question, what is the fasted way to perform an equivalent match, that is efficient looping through all 2000 rows?

Comment: 2000 rows is not a lot. In any case, with specific full working code you can post to Code Review and ask for optimizations... otherwise it's a bit hard to give suggestions.

Comment: "need to loop this through approx 2,000 rows, so I'm worried it will be too slow." How you think that an Excel function would find out the answer, intuitively? LOL. Loops are extremely quick; there are not too many things quicker than that. The in-built functions existing in almost any language (like the Excel functions) are usually pretty well-optimised, but further optimising what is almost optimal is not easy. Thus, the performance delivered by loops and by a function wouldn't differ much (and 2000 is not a big deal of rows). A lower number of code lines does not mean anything.

Comment: Believe me, 2000 rows will go by faster than you can blink.